# Вызов метода при нажатии на кнопку winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Разбираюсь потихоньку в `C#`.
Писала калькулятор `winForm`, появилась необходимость вынести всю логику в отдельный класс и вызывать его метод уже при нажатии на кнопку.
Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double first, second;
    first = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    second = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "+":
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(first + second);
            break;

        case "-":
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(first - second);
            break;

        case "*":
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(first * second);
            break;
    }

}
```

Подскажите, как я могу это реализовать?
Мне необходимо создать отдельный класс, к примеру calculate. Адаптировать код под него к примеру:

```
double first, second;
string rezult;
switch (rezult)
{
    case "+":
        Console.WriteLine(first + second);
        break;

    case "-":
        Console.WriteLine(first - second);
        break;
    
    case "*":
        Console.WriteLine(first * second);
        break;
}
```

Но думаю не совсем корректно во втором случае написан код, подскажите пожалуйста как будет правильнее и как я смогу вызвать метод из сторонего класса при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс в который инкапсулируется парсинг значений, парсинг операци и все вычисления:

```
public class CalcEngine
{ 
    public string Proceed(string action, string firstVar, string secondVar)
    {
        double first = Convert.ToDouble(firstVar);
        double second = Convert.ToDouble(secondVar);

        switch (action)
        {
            case "+":
                return Convert.ToString(first + second);

            case "-":
                return  Convert.ToString(first - second);

            case "*":
                return  Convert.ToString(first * second);
        }

        throw new Exception("Unknown action");
    }
}
```

Реакция на нажатие кнопки будет теперь выглядеть так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var calcEngine = new CalcEngine();
    textBox3.Text = calcEngine.Proceed(comboBox1.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Но при нажатии на button1 не происходит ничего, даже ошибок никаких при отладке не выдает.

Comment: Я поначалу неправильно написал код: не присвоил результат вычисления текст боксу. Проверьте, пожалуйста, что вы скопировали код после изменений и последняя строчка в `button1_Click` выгляидт так: `textBox3.Text = calcEngine.Proceed(comboBox1.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));`

Comment: Спасибо большое, поняла в чем была проблема, буду изучать данную тему дальше.